# Issue with Dockerising Django app using docker-compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and I want to dockerise the Django app to run as a container. Followed as below.

Here is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Here is `docker-compose.yml` conf

```
version: '3'

networks:
    mynetwork:
        driver: bridge

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: xxxxx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxxxx

  web:
    build: .
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      SEQ_DB: cath_local
      SEQ_USER: xxxxx
      SEQ_PW: xxxxx
      PORT: 5432
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://xxxxx:xxxxx@db:5432/cath_local

    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

    volumes:
      - .:/code

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

    depends_on:
      - db
```

well on my docker shell i point to Dockerfile directory, if i run an ls command from y path i see the manage.py file, but if i run:

```
docker-compose up
```

i get this error:

> web_1  | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   core_web_1 exited with code 2

Why my app don't find manage.py file that is in the same position as the "docker-compose up" command is?

PS: No /code folder is created when i run docker-compose command. Is it correct?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to edit your Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and remove `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` from `compose`

I assumed that the `manage.py` is in `/code/` folder, since you have `WORKDIR /code` in the `dockerfile` then the server will be created in the build stage and the files will be copied to it

Comment: seem to start but now i got error: db_1   | 2019-09-17 04:01:06.277 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-09-17 03:43:28 UTC
core_web_1 exited with code 0

Comment: check the logs `docker logs db`, I think you need to add the root passowrd for the db using `ENV` like the other in your `compose`

Comment: 2019-09-17 03:29:37.795 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-09-17 03:30:11.297 UTC [1] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2019-09-17 03:30:11.409 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 27) exited with exit code 1
2019-09-17 03:30:11.411 UTC [22] LOG:  shutting down
2019-09-17 03:30:11.463 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down

Comment: 2019-09-17 03:32:21.968 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2019-09-17 03:32:21.971 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2019-09-17 03:32:21.975 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-09-17 03:32:22.313 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-09-17 03:30:11 UTC

Comment: yes i try..but nothing change...i can't find what is killing my db proc

Comment: I think you need to post a new question for it

Answer (score 1):

as error states - `manage.py` is not in that directory.
And as far as I can see you are copying `requirements.txt` twice.

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
# move following line above 'pip install' and make sure that `manage.py` exists on the same directory as `requirements.txt`
COPY . /code/
# remove following line
# COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# you can define CMD here, but for dev env it is much more convenient to define it on docker-compose.yml, so you do not need to rebuild the image in case of some changes of the COMMAND
```