# Docker can't open file to run the python application in a container with django using docker-compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Django. I want to run the code of the example at https://github.com/wsvincent/djangoforprofessionals/tree/master/ch1-hello. The container is created but it doesn't run because it got interrupted since Docker can't start the application showing the following error when the command to run manage.py takes place.

```
Creating ch1-hello_web_1 ... done
Attaching to ch1-hello_web_1 web_1  | python: can't open 
file '/code/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
ch1-hello_web_1 exited with code 2
```

I'm using a Windows with windows 7 professional, therefore I have the Docker Toolbox working fine with other dockerized apps. I accessed the docker image and confirmed the file is in the container. So I would like to know if it could be Linux permissions when Docker tries to access the file.

I have Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a

The folder /code inside the docker image:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           361 Apr 23 02:11 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           157 Apr 11 21:31 Pipfile
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1624 Apr 11 21:31 Pipfile.lock
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        131072 Apr 11 21:31 db.sqlite3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           103 Apr 23 02:11 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Apr 23 00:38 hello_project
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           633 Apr 11 21:31 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Apr 23 00:38 pages
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3KEn.png Screenshot of the files at the image in Docker

Dockerfile I'm using, I changed to an alpine version. Notice that using the full python docker image, python:latest, I got the same error.

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.9.0a5-alpine3.10

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

I tried also making the changes suggested at a thread where someone reported the same error, in case that involved a database, but the problem remains. [Issue with Dockerising Django app using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57967183/issue-with-dockerising-django-app-using-docker-compose)

Thanks in advance!

## stayathome

Comment: Does it work if you use a final version of Python instead of an Alpha?

Comment: Hi Klaus, the same error is shown if I use the docker image **python:3.7**

Comment: The `volumes:` directive is overwriting the code in the image with whatever's in the host directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file, and that can lead to unpredictable behavior like this.  Does deleting the `volumes:` help?

Comment: check two things, your project needs to be at this location --> desktop/code/hello. Secondly docker will not work for windows i faced that issue too. So, you need to work on linux os (go for ubuntu 19.10) just install this os in virtual box of your windows pc.

Comment: You are absolutely right David, the problem is mounting the volume in windows. 

Yash, I'm still figuring out how to fix that. I could bind a folder like this ```docker run --rm -v c//temp/vols/code ch1-hello_web ls /code``` but then when trying to build it again another error is shown ```named volume is used by service but no declaration in found in volumes section````.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the book. This is a new Windows issue readers have alerted me too. One fix, strangely, is turn On "File and Printer Sharing" as [shown here](https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693/44).

Does that solve the issue for you?